# Unresolved Dependencies in SBT Multi Project

Tags: sbt, akka

Using sbt 13.8, the newest scala plugin for IntelliJ, and a new SBT project with Scala 2.11.7, I try to add a single library - akka 2.4.2. following [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/intro/getting-started.html#Using_Akka_with_SBT), i simply add

`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.2"`

But I am getting an unresolved dependency error:

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ...
>
> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ...
>
> [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last common/*:update' for the full output.
>
> [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last common/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
>
> [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last 
>   app1/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
>
> [error] (common/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka actor_2.10;2.4.2: not found
>
> [error] (common/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.4.2: not found
>
> [error] (app1/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: 
>   unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.4.2: not found

why is sbt trying to find `akka-actor_2.10` if I set project to 2.11.7?

UPDATE:

explicitly stating version,

`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.2"`

works but then you get an SBT project import warning:

> [warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
>
> [warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.7 [warn] in com.myorg#common$sources_2.10;1.0 differs from Scala binary version in project (2.10).
>
> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: 
>   [warn] * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.11.7, 2.10.4)...

EDIT:

build.sbt

```scala
import Dependencies._


name := "coolApps"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

lazy val common = (project in file("common")).
settings(Commons.settings: _*).
settings(
libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
 // dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value
)

lazy val app1 = (project in file("app1")).
 settings(Commons.settings: _*).
 settings(
libraryDependencies ++= app1Dependencies
 ).
dependsOn(common)
```

Dependencies.scala

```scala
object Dependencies {


val akka = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.2"


val commonDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
 akka
 )

val app1Dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq()
}
```

Commons.scala

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._


object Commons {
  val coolAppVersion = "1.0"

  val settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
   organization := "com.company",
   version := coolAppVersion,
   scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8"),
   resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
  )
 )
}
```

Comment: What's your build.sbt?

Comment: ill make an edit and add build.sbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build.sbt, you need to set the key

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

If you don't set this, it'll use the scala used by SBT itself which is a 2.10.x version.

Comment: Is it maybe the case when doing SBT Multiproject that you have to set scalaVersion in each of the subprojects?

Comment: Yes. that solved it. I changed the question to a more relevant one in case someone searches, and this is a reminder to set Scala Version in subprojects as well ( in my case adding scalaVersion to common settings)

Comment: Yep.. each project is separate from the other and so doesn't inherit any settings. I am sure you know.. but for other observers.. if you do 'show scalaVersion', it'll show you scalaVersion of all projects that should help debug this.